# Why can't HashingTF in Spark MLib produce sparse vectors?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

Why does the maximum number of features produced by `HashingTF` (number of buckets) has to be limited? I've tried to set it to `Int.MaxValue`, but it runs out of memory while trying to allocate a huge array. Why can't it produce a sparse vector?

Comment: __It does return `SparseVector`__, you cannot accommodate `Array` larger than max integer, hence you cannot have `Vector` larger than that (neither Sparse or Dense) and if there is dimensionality reduction achieved by hashing trick there is no point in using `HashingTF`. This is where you use `CountVectorizer`.

Comment: I didn't understand anything in your comment. HashingTF hashes every token in the input and counts occurrences for each hash value, so semantically it transforms `Seq[Token]` to `Seq[(Hash, Count)]`. My question is: why limit the range for the hash value, if you can use sparse representation?

Comment: In practice it is actually `(Array[Hash], Array[Count])`. The point is that array cannot be larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Since in the worst case scenario representation will be effectively dense (all buckets are covered) this is the hard limit. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Now I understand why number of features can't be more than `Int.MaxValue` (however, it's hard to imagine a dataset with that many features). But I'm still confused why is it causing OOM on a fairly small dataset (as it was allocating a dense vector instead of sparse). Leaving the default setting helps (which is 2**20, according to documentation).

Comment: Yes, it is highly unlikely.  And useless in practice. _as it was allocating a dense vector instead of sparse_ - it doesn't. I've shared a link to the exact implementation. It doesn't use `DenseVector` even if it would be preferable memory wise. OOM can be result of different things, including to much pressure on the GC.